# Joining tables without common columns

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables as below, one with Question table and other with option values but without common columns and also pasted the expected output.
here i have used Outer Apply to get the result. could  anyone suggest is there any better way this can be coded to get result faster.

```
CREATE TABLE #T1
(
COL1 VARCHAR(10),
COL2 VARCHAR(10)
)


CREATE TABLE #T2
(
COL1 VARCHAR(20),
COL2 VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES('Country1','State1')
INSERT INTO #T1 VALUES('Country1','State2')

INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES('State1options','City1')
INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES('State1options','City2')
INSERT INTO #T2 VALUES('State2options','State3')

---Current code and run to get Expected output
Select Col1,Col2,Coalesce(Op1,Op2) as StateOptions
From
(
Select A.col1,A.col2,B.col2 as Op1,C.Col2 as Op2 From #T1 A
Outer Apply
( Select col2 from #T2 Where Col1='State1options'
 And A.COL2='State1'    ) B
 Outer Apply
( Select col2 from #T2 Where Col1='State2options'
 And A.COL2='State2'    ) C
 ) t

Drop table #T1

Drop table #T2
```

Expectation is to get similar output with better optimized query.

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: Thanks for checking the post.  Query pasted in my link would give the result i expects

Comment: It looks like `SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.col1 LIKE CONCAT(t1.col2, '%')`  ?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to improve the schema before trying to improve the query. SQL without a relational database model is like hammering a nail with a saw.

Comment: Totally agreed redesign of schema would give better performance and query also will be become simpler but due to process introducing new table would take time here. Could you confirm whether the current query pasted in my thread is the correct approach to get my expected results .  Is there any alternative other an Outer apply?